# What is the easiest way to write from an Array to a CSV file?

Tags: objective-c, csv, nsarray

What is the easiest way to export from an array to a CSV file? I was planning on using a for loop and inserting commas into the string, but realized I don't know how to change the txt file into a CSV file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: save the file with .csv extension..that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use

```
NSString *csvString = [/*name of array*/ componentsJoinedByString:@","];

//Create file manager, pick path, etc

[/*name of file manager*/ createFileAtPath:/*file path*/ contents:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
```

I only ever use it to create a .csv file from an array of floats or strings. If you have formatting characters in your data you might have to call an escape-addition method before you generate the .csv to get everything to look like you want.

If you want multiple lines in a .csv then you need to add `\n` at each line break (if you don't already have it).

Answer (score 0):

just save/open the file as .csv file. for example, if you now save/open as test.txt, just use test.csv

BTW, if the text value has ',' in it, you need use " " for that field. otherwise, it will not be a 100% compatible csv file.